# How to validate s/mime signature using openssl

Tags: macos, openssl, smime

How to validate s/mime signature using OpenSSL. Through command line we can verify with:

```
openssl smime -verify -in detachedsign.pem -content content.txt
```

What is the equivalent method for `openssl smime -verify` command on Mac OSX?

Answer (score 2):

> what is the equalant method for openssl smime -verify command in mac osx apps

There is none out of the box. Mac OS X provides OpenSSL 0.9.8y. `openssl smime` was added at OpenSSL 1.0.0. See [`smime(1)`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/smime.html) for details.

0.9.8 is also missing `cms`. And I don't believe you can use `pkcs7` - the sub commands look anemic.

You can use OpenSSL if you build and install OpenSSL on OS X. If you build it, configure with `Configure darwin64-x86_64-cc`. Once installed, the newer OpenSSL will be located at `/usr/local/ssl/bin` by default.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, for verifiying s/mime signatures on OSX, you have

`security cms -D -i smime-message-in-der-format.der`

I think you need the message to be in DER instead of PEM format. I don't know about `-content`, could that be the equivalent of `-envelope`?